# JavaScript: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby

When I try to pass a string as an argument in the following function, I get the `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error. It works fine when passing integers though. I am confused because I read a string must be passed as the argument, and not an integer.

**HTML:**

```
r.title = "The large item"
counter = <integer>

<% @items.each do |r| %>
  <p>Title: <%= r.title %></p>
  <p>Price: <%= r.price %></p>
  <p>Description: <%= r.description %></p>
  <p style="color:blue;" class="room_<%= counter %>" onclick='addItemToCart(<%= r.title %>, <%= counter %>)'>Select Item</p>
  <br>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

When I pass `r.id` in place of `r.title`, the code works.

**JavaScript:**

```
<script text/javascript>
  function addItemToCart(title, item_number){
    $("#" + item_number).append("<br>"+title);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're missing quotes around the string. Try this:

```
<p style="color:blue;" class="room_<%= counter %>"
   onclick='addItemToCart("<%= r.title %>", <%= counter %>)'>Select Item</p>
```

**EDIT**

To understand the issue, try looking at the HTML it outputs. I imagine you'll see something like this:

```
<p style="color:blue;" class="room_123"
   onclick='addItemToCart(The large item, 123)'>Select Item</p>
```

Hopefully, the missing quotes are obvious from that output.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Do you know why `<%=  r.title.to_s %>` does not work?

Comment: For the same reason... you need to put quotes around the string.

Comment: What happens if `r.title` contains a double quote?

Comment: See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript.

Answer (score 1):

With php and js, I had the same error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[image]

[image]

##### 1. Replace null values with empty string

In php, I had to add  `?? ''` after each value of a variable, the first time that variable is used in the code:

```php
var new_value = $("#update").find(  'input[name="'+
                                    x['x_name']+
                                    '_x_value"]').val() ?? '';
if(x['x_value'] ?? '' != new_value) { 
    ...
```

In javascript, you would replace null with `""` like

```js
(value === null) ? "" : value
```

##### 2. User rights

Also check your user rights if you use a back-end with permissions. My user had only read rights. Screenshots from DBeaver:

[image]

That can lead to an empty response from the sql db in my case. Not in your case, but it may help someone else.

##### 3. Check for too many brackets

I also got this error when I had a double closing `}` bracket where only one was needed.

##### 4. Official guide for the error

If that does not fix it, have a look at the "Learn More" link in the error message: [SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @smarx, but I think this is a typical sample of mixing HTML, Javascript and Ruby snippet together, which should always be avoided.

The better way is to at least separate Ruby snippet from Javascript.

**ERB**

```
<p style="color:blue;" class="room_<%= counter %>"
  data-title="<%= r.title %>"
  data-counter="<%= counter %>"
  onclick='addItemToCart(this)'>Select Item</p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function addItemToCart(element) {
  var title = element.dataset.title;
  var counter = element.dataset.counter;
  // ...
}
```

You can see that I added two `data-*` attributes to the HTML, and read them in the Javascript. This seems a little verbose, but it's less spaghetti, and it clearly separates the code running on server (Ruby) from the code running on browsers (Javascript).

P.S. If you're using jQuery, I would strongly recommend *NOT* to use `onclick` attribute, because it requires you to define global functions. Use `$(...).click(fn)` or `$(...).on('click', fn)` instead, because it allows anonymous non-global functions.